# How to add a timestamp to a ManyToMany record

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, many-to-many

I have the following model:

```
class Meeting(models.Model):
    meeting_title = models.CharField(default='', max_length=128, blank=True, null=True)
    meeting_time = models.TimeField(blank=False, null=False)
    meeting_date = models.DateField(blank=False, null=False) 
    meeting_visitors = models.ManyToManyField(Visitor, blank=True, default="")
```

And the following form:

```
class AddMeetingForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
            model = Meeting
            fields = '__all__'
```

As `meeting_visitors` is a `ManyToMany` field, it can contain one or multiple `Visitor` records.

This form can be updated at different times during the day. I want to know the timestamp of each `Visitor` that is added to the meeting (i.e. in the real world, when they arrived at the meeting).

What is the easiest / most efficient way to do this?

I know I can get the `timestamp` that the Model instance was updated via `meeting_updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add =False, auto_now=True)` but I want the equivalent for each record in the `meeting_visitors` field.

Comment: This is what you need https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/models/#extra-fields-on-many-to-many-relationships

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can easily create this relationship using the `through` keyword in the many to many field

> Django allows you to specify the model that will be used to govern the
>   many-to-many relationship. You can then put extra fields on the
>   intermediate model. The intermediate model is associated with the
>   ManyToManyField using the through argument to point to the model that
>   will act as an intermediary.

Therefore, you can use it this way.

```
class Visitor(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)

class Meeting(model.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    time = models.TimeField(blank=False, null=False)
    date = models.DateField(blank=False, null=False) 
    attendance = models.ManyToManyField(Visitor, through='Attendant')


class Attendant(models.Model):
    visitors = models.ForeignKey(Visitor)
    meeting = models.ForeignKey(Meeting)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

Comment: how to get the created or updated field through relation. meeting_obj.attendance.all() get visitor queryset, how can i get Attendant queryset